# How is Java compiler without type casting calling a correct equals() function in subclass?

Tags: java, android, inheritance, equals

I have `ScheduledSessionViewModel` class which extends `AbstractSessionViewModel`. Both this functions have implementation of **equals()** function.

```
class AbstractSessionViewModel {
   @Override public boolean equals(Object o) {
      return /* some logic */
   }
}

class ScheduledSessionViewModel extends AbstractSessionViewModel {
   @Override public boolean equals(Object o) {
      if (!super.equals(o)) return false;

      return /* some logic */;
   }
}
```

Since I'm using Androids new `ListAdapter` I am implementing `DiffUtil.ItemCallback<T>` and I have next method:

```
@Override public boolean areContentsTheSame(AbstractSessionViewModel oldItem, AbstractSessionViewModel newItem) {
   if (oldItem instanceof ScheduledSessionViewModel && !(newItem instanceof ScheduledSessionViewModel)){
     return false;
   } else if (!(oldItem instanceof ScheduledSessionViewModel) && newItem instanceof ScheduledSessionViewModel){
     return false;
   } else if (oldItem instanceof ScheduledSessionViewModel){
     return ((ScheduledSessionViewModel)oldItem).equals((ScheduledSessionViewModel)newItem);
   } else {
     return oldItem.equals(newItem);
   }
}
```

What's weird here is that compiler is showing me warning that in the next statement

> ((ScheduledSessionViewModel)oldItem).equals((ScheduledSessionViewModel)newItem);

**type cast is unnecessary**.

How is this possible? How's Java compiler able to detect that `oldItem` is of type `ScheduledSessionViewModel`?

Comment: Both are `Object`s, right? That's what the `equals()` signature is expecting as input.

Comment: Just like it calls any other (overloaded) method. If `oldItem` is a `ScheduledSessionViewModel` it will call the 'latest' overloaded method. For all your needs you could have defined `oldItem` as an `Object` and it would still work. Same for `toString`, or any other method you'll define.

Comment: Ok, so if I wanted to call a function which is not implemented in `AbstractSessionViewModel ` I'll have to cast the object, in other cases simple function call would be sufficient since it'll call he 'latest' overloaded method.
Thanks, @M.leRutte, I think I get it.

Comment: Note: Procedures that operate on objects are called *methods* rather than *functions*.

Comment: You don't ever have to typecast in the context of usage of `equals`. Every object of any class has it (either by its own implementation or by inheritance), and the `equals` method accepts any object.

Comment: @Mlerutte You are actually talking about *overriding* instead of *overloading*. Overloading is the event of **defining a method with the same name as another method, but with different parameters.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How's Java compiler able to detect that `oldItem` is of type `ScheduledSessionViewModel`?

No it is not; the compiler only knows that `oldItem` is of type `AbstractSessionViewModel`.

But it doesn't matter. The compiler knows that the `AbstractSessionViewModel` has the `equals(Object)` method, so the *actual* object type has it too. In this way the compiler guarantees that the `equals(Object)` method is available at runtime.

*How* it is implemented is only known at runtime. The runtime searches the appropriate method based on a set of rules defined by the JLS.

Answer (score 0):

Side note: After the clarification above, I came up with the conclusion that with properly implemented `equals()` method, a method bellow

```
@Override public boolean areContentsTheSame(AbstractSessionViewModel oldItem, AbstractSessionViewModel newItem) {
  if (oldItem instanceof ScheduledSessionViewModel && !(newItem instanceof ScheduledSessionViewModel)){
    return false;
  } else if (!(oldItem instanceof ScheduledSessionViewModel) && newItem instanceof ScheduledSessionViewModel){
    return false;
  } else if (oldItem instanceof ScheduledSessionViewModel){
    return ((ScheduledSessionViewModel)oldItem).equals((ScheduledSessionViewModel)newItem);
  } else {
    return oldItem.equals(newItem);
  }
}
```

can be refactored and that if statements are unnecessary. Implementation of `equals()` method should take care of everything.

End result:

```
@Override public boolean areContentsTheSame(AbstractSessionViewModel oldItem, AbstractSessionViewModel newItem) {
    return oldItem.equals(newItem);
}
```